# Wireshare Check for Torrentz

Tags: wireshark, bittorrent, utorrent

I want to use wireshark to check which network users is using Port 59666 for downloads. Is it possible to use wireshark? and how would I begin to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to do this with wireshark, but it may require you to adjust your network topology to achieve this.

Firstly you need to decide where to run wireshark.

Wireshark can only tell you about network packets that it can see. To assist, wireshark can put the network card into promiscuous mode, but if the network card is connected to a switch, the switch will not send other network packets to you - so wireshark cannot report on them.

If your users are connected using wifi, then you can run wireshark on a wifi addapter and inspect all wifi network packets from all users  on that wifi network. You may also install wireshark on a computer operating as the router / firewall, and inspect all the packets there.

The final option depends on your switch hardware.  On managed switches it is usually possible to duplicate all network traffic to an additional port.  That would allow you to connect your computer to this port, and then run wireshark on this network connection.

When you are receiving the wireshark trace, set up a filter for the ports you are interested in, and wait for your users to send packets.  Inspect the packets, and you will see the source IP address.  You now need to translate this IP address to a physical computer (DNS / DHCP servers may help with this).

Depending on your computer environment, tracking it down to a single computer may not identify an individual responsible.  Someone could have left a torrent running in the background and someone else could have logged onto and used the machine.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your thoughts, it's pretty much what i thought I may have to do, run everyone's internet through one of my servers on the site. I'd intsal a packet capture on each of the PCs if I could however people use personal latops and all sorts, and need to so we can't block out unknown devices for example.

Just as a talking point. What about if it was run through a hub rather than a switch. My understanding of old school hubs (for example old BT hubs) are that they send traffic out to all ports/devices simultaniously? Would this work in reverse somehow?

Comment: Yes an old school hub could work - if the overall network traffic was low enough. If a significant proportion of the traffic was port to port on the switch being replaced rather than port to uplink then you could introduce a packet collision problem crippling your bandwidth.